# MySql SUM function unable to get desired results

Tags: mysql, group-by, phpmyadmin, sum

I have a table named 'money_table' as follow:

```
id    money_type    category    amount
1     EURO          CASH        2000
2     US_DOLLAR     CASH        3000
3     RUPEE         DD          4000
4     EURO          DD          5000
5     US_DOLLAR     DD          2000
6     EURO          CASH        6000
7     RUPEE         CASH        4500
8     US_DOLLAR     CASH        3000
9     EURO          NEFT        1000
```

I want results as below:

```
money_type    CASH    DD    NEFT
EURO          8000    5000  1000
US_DOLLAR     6000    2000  0
RUPEE         4500    4000  0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below using conditional aggregation

```
select money_type, sum(case when category='CASH' then amount end) as CASH,
sum(case when category='DD' then amount end) as DD,
sum(case when category='NEFT' then amount end) as NEFT
from tablename
group by money_type
```